# Login page not redirecting properly

Tags: asp.net

I have created 2 folders in my asp.net project. (Account and AdminFolder)
I want to restrict the Register.aspx page to Admin users only.

My Login.aspx page is in the Account folder and I have included a web.config in that folder with the following code;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have placed the Register.aspx file in the AdminFolder with the following web.config code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/> 
    <deny users="*"/> 
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

In testing this approach out, I have tried to launch the application by going directly to the Register.aspx file. As expected, I am redirected to the Login.aspx page.

The url showing up in the browser is

```
http://localhost:49319/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdminFolder%2fRegister.aspx
```

I login as an Admin user and I can see that I am logged in as my header hyperlink changes to logout. (I can also navigate to other files in Account to confirm I am logged in) However, the application remains at the login page instead of redirecting to the Register.aspx page.

I expected to be redirected to the Register.aspx page when login was successful.

Even once I am logged in as Admin user, I am unable to navigate directly to the Register.aspx page. I am redirected to Login.aspx.

I confirmed (by way of my Sql Server database) that the user in my test case is in the Admin role.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction here? Thanks in advance for you time and consideration.

Comment: are you saying that you are unable to navigate directly to URL 
http://localhost:49319/Account/register.aspx   
,after login?

Comment: My Register.aspx file is in my AdminFolder. After login, I am unable to navigate directly to http://localhost:49319/AdminFolder/Register.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your web.config in `AdminFolder` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator"/>
   <deny users="?"/> 
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Typically that is the `RoleName` as it appears in the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Still returning the login screen.

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove:
 <deny users="*"/>
Hopefully that does the trick and behaves as you intended?

Comment: Unfortunately that would also allow anonymous users to access the page. I see my error now. I was allowing Admin role and then denying all roles. I will post my update.

Comment: Thanks very much DaniDev for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Yeah we finally got on the right track.
Glad I helped you find the right combination.

Answer (score 0):

I see my error. I was allowing Admin role and then denying all roles (which would include Admin). I should have used the following in AdminFolder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for all the feedback.